# Only search text user has selected

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm used to working with Selection.WholeStory, but now have a macro where I make a lot of search and replace operations. I only want the module to search and replace in the selection the user has selected before running the macro.

How can I do this? I've tried Selection.Text, but Word tells me this is invalid use of the Text property.

**ADDED:**
My module starts like this

```
Sub Bibliography()

With ActiveDocument
        .TrackRevisions = False
        .PrintRevisions = False
        .ShowRevisions = False
End With
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
```

By not specifying the selection object I should get only the selection the user has already made before running the macro. But this doesn't seem to work. For instance, the code below changes the occurences in the entire document, not just in the selection made by the user

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "%"
    .Replacement.Text = " %"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: have you seen [**this?**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821411.aspx)

Comment: Yes, it says: "If no object qualifier is used with the Selection property, Microsoft Word returns the selection from the active pane of the active document window." - However, if I don't specify something Word searches/replaces in the entire document.

Comment: show the code you have for 'search-replace'. I think you are close or you almost have it but I need to see your code to provide additional help. Have you tried with macro recorder- it should provide you a correct syntax.

Comment: Good idea, thanks - will try the recorder first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion you only need to change one line:

```
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
```

into this one:

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

But keep also in mind that if nothing is selected (single cursor is blinking) than your code will run for whole document. To avoid such a thing you could try either Mehow solution (not sure if it will work) or you could add simple `if statement` at the beginning:

```
If Selection.Range.Start = Selection.Range.End Then
    MsgBox "Select something, please!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: OK, will try that - what does wdFindStop mean? That it should not continue past the selection?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much. I think this is the second time you have helped me out with great advice.